# Best practices for running a rootless container as a systemd service with User= or --user?

Tags: systemd, non-root-user, podman

I'm experimenting with running rootless containers with Podman as systemd services. I'd also like to run the services themselves with non-root privileges, either:

a) as a system service, but with `User=` set to a service user, or
b) as a user service (`systemd --user`) of that service user, having previously run `loginctl enable-linger <username>` to allow for long-running services.

The idea is to standardize our future approach for small-scale daemonless & rootless container deployments in production, but I'm not entirely sure which of these approaches to pick, as I don't know all the pitfalls. Below, some background discussion with actual questions in boldface.

As an initial experiment, I'm running the `maptiler/tileserver-gl` image to serve map tiles from local filesystem sources.

One thing I've noticed is that with option a, there seems to be no built-in way inside a unit file to access any information about the user specified as `User=` (see ["Specifiers" in systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers); e.g., `%t` points to `/run`, and `%h` points to `/root`). This is relevant because I originally created the unit file for `tileserver-gl` with `podman generate systemd --new`, where `--new` conveniently creates and destroys the container on every start and stop, using `--cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id` in `ExecStart=` to create (and delete in `ExecStartPre=`) a file that contains the container ID. Of course, our service user has no write access to `/run`. This is not a dealbreaker, as I can simply hardcode `/run/user/<uuid>` instead of `%t` (or use a non-recreating method of running the container), but the loss of "dynamism" is a shame. **Is there a way of getting the UID of the `User=` user from within a system service file and inserting it into the `ExecStart=` command that I've missed?**

If my understanding is correct, apparently neither option can bind to TCP and UDP ports below 1024 without workarounds ([this one](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/sysctl/#optional-allowing-listening-on-tcp--udp-ports-below-1024) looks rather good for our case). I initially thought that `User=` services could perform the binding before dropping privileges, but apparently that's not the case. Based on some research, the most "systemd-native" way is to use socket units to achieve this, but it appears to require the running service to actively support it. **Is it correct that neither option can "natively" bind to sub-1024 ports without socket units, and even while using those, only in certain cases?**

Ultimately, I'm looking for best practices here. Depending on what source you read, some people emphasize `--user` for ephemeral services for the duration of login sessions, but OTOH the existence of `enable-linger` seems to indicate wider applicability to long-running sessions. **What salient pros and cons do you see for the two options? Which option do you consider the better one for this "service user" case, and why?**

Comment: `--user` does address all of the problems you mentioned with `User=`.  There is nothing wrong with using `enable-linger` and that's exactly what it's for.  Go with `--user` and the `enable-linger` option.

Comment: I believe using `User=` is not yet supported. See https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778#issuecomment-1025671306

Comment: @ErikSjölund ah, good find. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: https://blog.christophersmart.com/2021/02/20/rootless-podman-containers-under-system-accounts-managed-and-enabled-at-boot-with-systemd/ walks through the process step-by-step. I originally found that article a long time ago, but didn't completely "grok" it until recently. Best I've yet seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running rootless Podman in a systemd system service using the systemd directive `User=` is currently not supported.

See [feature request](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778) in the Podman GitHub project.

**Update November 21, 2023:**

I guess the feature is still not officially supported but I created systemd system service with `User=test`, `Type=notify` and `Delegate=yes`:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Requires=user@1000.service
After=user@1000.service
RequiresMountsFor=/run/user/1000/containers

[Service]
User=test
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
KillMode=mixed
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid
ExecStopPost=-/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid
Delegate=yes
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
SyslogIdentifier=%N
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run \
     --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid \
     --cgroups=split \
     --rm \
     --env "NGINX=3;" \
      -d \
     --replace \
     --name systemd-%N \
     --sdnotify=conmon \
     docker.io/library/nginx
```

I tried to stay as close as possible to how Quadlet-generated services look like.

Test the web server. It seems to work.

```
$ curl localhost:80 | head -4
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

In the example I also used a socket unit to be able to listen on a privileged port. For details, see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762009/9360

I have just tried this out so I still need to figure out how well this solution works.

References:

Example 3 and 4 here:
https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation/

Comment: Post-update comment: thanks for the heads up, I need to look into this. (For historical reference, at the time of accepting it, this answer used to say that `User=` is not yet supported, in accordance with Erik's original comment on my question).

Comment: I made a quick test with Podman 4.2 and Fedora 36 but I couldn't get `Type=notify` to work. Probably it's easier to get it working with `Type=forking`.

Comment: The issue has been reopened – appears that it's not supported after all.

Answer (score 1):

The following has been tested under RHEL 8.6 and 9.1, podman 4.0.2, with SELinux enabled. The service is started without requiring the user to log in.

Linux user svcacct has user id 1000. Shell scripts `launchContainers.sh` and `shutdownContainers.sh` contain the appropriate podman commands to start and stop a pod. The scripts can be used and tested in isolation from systemd. `loginctl enable-linger svcacct` was run once as a sudo user. The systemd unit from /etc/systemd/system/ is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Demo Containers

Requires=user@1000.service
After=user@1000.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true

ExecStart=/usr/local/demo/launchContainers.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/demo/shutdownContainers.sh

User=svcacct
Group=svcacct

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case and honestly find it surprising that there is not yet better support for it: it seems the perfect intersection of the long-standing best practice of running services as limited-privilege service accounts and the Podman best practice of running containers rootlessly whenever possible.

Considering how many applications/services are now delivered as containers, for good reason, running service containers as service users just seems like a natural best practice.

My "solution", such as it is, is to use system services with `runuser`, which I've found to be the most scriptable solution so far. I still have to create the container image as the user, but, again, that is scriptable with `runuser`. I haven't spent a lot of time looking into scripting `machinectl` but as far as I can tell from my research, alternatives based on `machinectl`, etc., all require running an interactive shell as the service user, which breaks scriptability.

So the basic idea is

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/runuser -u serviceUser myCntnrBuildScript containerName
# myCntnrBuildScript does
# _mnt=$(${BUILDAH} mount $_containerImage)
# populate ${_mnt}, e.g., via cp, etc.
# ${BUILDAH} commit $_containerImage $_containerName
# etc., where the various variables are managed in my script
...

# then, in the systemd file,
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -u serviceUser -- /usr/bin/podman run --cidfile=%t/user/$(id -u serviceUser)/__cidfile__ ...
...
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/runuser -u cds-ipa -- /usr/bin/podman stop --ignore --cidfile=%t/user/$(id -u serviceUser)/__cidfile__
# in practice, `$(id -u serviceUser)` does not appear in the systemd file,
# which is generated programmatically: `$(id -u serviceUser)` appears in
# the script that generates the systemd file.
```

TBH, the use of `--cidfile=%t/user/$(id -u serviceUser)/__cidfile__` is really a sort of "received wisdom" approach to getting this working when I first started on this path. Now that I understand how the pieces work together a bit better, I am thinking of replacing `%t/user/$(id -u serviceUser)` with something more specific to my use case, since I could use `ExecStartPre` statements to create a serviceUser-readable directory on a `tmpfs` for this purpose and `ExecStopPost` statements to clean that up, if necessary, but the `%t/user/` approach works, so if it ain't broke....