# Rootless podman container with privileged port mapping

Tags: linux, container, podman

Is there a way to start a rootless podman container with mapped privileged port (container service is exposed through host's port 1023 or lower)?

Running

```
$ podman run --rm -it  -p 80:80 nginx:stable-alpine 
Error: rootlessport cannot expose privileged port 80, you can add 'net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=80' to /etc/sysctl.conf (currently 1024), or choose a larger port number (>= 1024): listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: permission denied
```

naturally fails because of insufficient permissions.

```
$ sudo capsh --caps=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE+eip  -- -c 'podman run --rm -it  -p 80:80 nginx:stable-alpine'
```

runs podman as a `root` user

```
$ sudo capsh --caps=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE+eip --user=$USER -- -c 'podman run --rm -it  -p 80:80 nginx:stable-alpine'
Unable to set group list for user: Operation not permitted
```

fails because of `su` permissions.

So far I ended up with a sub-optimal solution that temporarily allows any process to bind a privileged port for couple of seconds:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=80 ;\
( sleep 5 ; sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024 ) &\
podman run --rm -it  -p 80:80 nginx:stable-alpine
```

Comment: It looks like you've explored all the options: either set `net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` to allow unprivileged processes to bind to low-numbered ports, or run `podman` with additional privileges using `capsh`. You're trying to perform a privileged operation as an unprivileged user, so you're going to need some form of privilege escalation.

Comment: It should be possible to use `setcap` to set the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability on the podman binary itself, but this didn't seem to work in a quick test just now.

Comment: Maybe in the future it will be possible to run an _nginx_ container with rootless Podman via _socket activation_ and a _systemd system service_ (with [`User=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=)). _socket activation_ support for __docker.io/library/nginx__ will hopefully be available soon ([my PR was merged](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/pull/703)). I don't know the current status regarding Podman support for systemd system services with `User=`.

Comment: The container image __docker.io/library/nginx__ now supports _socket activation_. There is still no support for the systemd environment variables `LISTEN_FDS`, `LISTEN_FDNAMES`, `LISTEN_PID` but the environment variable `NGINX` lets you combine a systemd socket unit with nginx. See also my demo: https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation The next thing to investigate will be how to combine that with [`User=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=).

Comment: @czerny How well has your solution held up in practice? I'm facing the same problem and I'm considering using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rootless Podman in a `User=` systemd service can start the nginx container with *socket activation* using a privileged port.

1. Create the user *test* if it does not yet exist.

   ```
   $ sudo useradd test
   ```
2. Check the UID of the user *test*

   ```
   $ id -u test
   1000
   ```
3. Create the file */etc/systemd/system/example3.service* with the contents

   ```
   [Unit]
   Wants=network-online.target
   After=network-online.target
   Requires=user@1000.service
   After=user@1000.service
   RequiresMountsFor=/run/user/1000/containers

   [Service]
   User=test
   Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
   KillMode=mixed
   ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid
   ExecStopPost=-/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid
   Delegate=yes
   Type=notify
   NotifyAccess=all
   SyslogIdentifier=%N
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run \
        --cidfile=/run/user/1000/%N.cid \
        --cgroups=split \
        --rm \
        --env "NGINX=3;" \
         -d \
        --replace \
        --name systemd-%N \
        --sdnotify=conmon \
        docker.io/library/nginx
   ```

   (To adjust the file for your system, replace `1000` with the UID found in step 2)
4. Optional step for improved security: Edit the file */etc/systemd/system/example3.service*
   and add the option `--network none` to the `podman run` command.
   For details, see section [*Possibility to restrict the network in the container*](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/socket-activation-podman)
5. Create the file */etc/systemd/system/example3.socket* with the contents

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Example 3 socket

   [Socket]
   ListenStream=0.0.0.0:80

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sockets.target
   ```
6. Reload the systemd configuration

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
7. Start the socket

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl start example3.socket
   ```
8. Test the web server

   ```
   $ curl localhost:80 | head -4
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
   ```

Note that the method used in this example requires that the container image supports *socket activation*. For example **docker.io/library/mariadb** and **docker.io/library/nginx** support *socket activation* but many other container images do not support *socket activation*.

The steps above are from a demo I wrote:
https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation/tree/main/examples/example3

I have just tried this out so I still need to figure out how well this solution works.

There is a [Podman feature request](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/20573)
for adding Podman support for `User=` in systemd system services. The feature request was moved into a GitHub discussion.